# how to always set my footer in the bottom is it possible with css only

Tags: html, css

I have a div class .footer which is my website's footer till now I do not have any content on my webpage so it is on the top of my page after my navigation.
please tell some CSS so I can make my footer at the bottom of my page.

Comment: Do it with the flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `position:fixed` on footer and setting `bottom:0` will position ur footer at the bottom of screen

More about CSS positions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  some content
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used in order to do that:

```
#footer{
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

`position: fixed;` will get the position fixed while scrolling & `bottom:0` will keep the element at bottom of window.

```css
    .footer{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        background-color:red;
    }
    
    .header{
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        background-color:green;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header">
       Header
</div>

<div class="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but if i fix the position it will always remains on the same place.

Comment: It will always remain at bottom.. and inner content will scroll.

Comment: You can use flexbox for that. Check out this sample snippet I created to see how that can work: https://jsfiddle.net/stephenasamoah/e4v6g1p7/3/